Accurate drawings of field lines in three situations
I am looking for accurate drawings of the electric and magnetic field lines in three situations:

The electric field lines formed between a positive point charge and negative point charge. (i.e. the field lines associated with an electric dipole).
The magnetic field lines formed between two parallel wires when the electrical currents are,
a) flowing in the same direction,
b) flowing in the opposite direction.

The drawings need only show the field lines in the plane and in the case of 2a and 2b the wires should be perpendicular to the plane.
The shape of the field lines in the all the drawings I have found using a search are similar in appearance but they aren't all identical. I would really like to know the true or ideal shape of the field lines. Thanks in advance.

How to write the equation of a field line of an electrostatic field? and Equation describing the electric field lines of opposite charges give answers to  your question 1.

Related : Trajectory of electric field lines.

@Frobenius I did not forget your fabulous answer! That is my second link.

$\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} 
\newcommand{\e}{\bl=}
\newcommand{\p}{\bl+}
\newcommand{\m}{\bl-}
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbf {#1}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal {#1}}
\newcommand{\mr}[1]{\mathrm {#1}}
\newcommand{\mf}[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\bl>}
\newcommand{\les}{\bl<}
\newcommand{\greq}{\bl\ge}
\newcommand{\leseq}{\bl\le}
\newcommand{\il}[1]{$\:#1\:$}
\newcommand{\plr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\blr}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\clr}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\vlr}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\Vlr}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\lara}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lav}[1]{\left\langle#1\right|}
\newcommand{\vra}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavra}[2]{\left\langle#1|#2\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavvra}[3]{\left\langle#1\right|#2\left|#3\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\vp}{\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\newcommand{\Vp}[1]{\vphantom{#1}}
\newcommand{\hp}[1]{\hphantom{#1}} 
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}$
ANSWER$\bl{\m01}$
(2.b) The magnetic field lines formed between two parallel wires when the electrical currents are flowing in the opposite direction.
The differential equation to be solved is
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mr dy}{\mr dx} \e \dfrac{B_y\plr{x,y}}{B_x\plr{x,y}}
\tl{01}
\end{equation}
By a first glance it seems to be difficult or may be impossible to succeed separation of the used variables $\:\plr{x,y}$. We will solve this equation by a proper change of variables. The new variables are
\begin{equation}
u \e \tan\theta_{\mr A} \,,\qquad v \e \tan\theta_{\mr B}
\tl{02}
\end{equation}
where $\:\plr{\theta_{\mr A},\theta_{\mr B}}\:$ the angles shown in Figure-01 .
Using the geometry of the problem we'll transform the differential equation \eqref{01} with respect to $\:\plr{x,y}\:$ to a differential equation  with respect to $\:\plr{ u, v}$. The new differential equation is separable and we note a priori that its solution yields the result
\begin{equation}
\sin\theta_{\mr B} \e \lambda \sin\theta_{\mr A} 
\nonumber
\end{equation}
where $\:\lambda\:$ a constant factor. To each permissible value of $\:\lambda\:$ there corresponds a magnetic field line.
At first from the geometry of the problem we have
\begin{equation}
\plr{x \m a}\tan\theta_{\mr B} \e y \e \plr{x \p a}\tan\theta_{\mr A}
\nonumber
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\plr{x \m a} v \e y \e \plr{x \p a} u
\tl{03}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
x \e \dfrac{\tan\theta_{\mr B}\p\tan\theta_{\mr A}}{\tan\theta_{\mr B}\m\tan\theta_{\mr A}}\, a \,,\qquad y \e \dfrac{2\tan\theta_{\mr B} \tan\theta_{\mr A}}{\tan\theta_{\mr B} \m \tan\theta_{\mr A}}\, a
\tl{04}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
x \e \plr{\dfrac{v\p u}{v\m u}} a \,,\qquad y \e \plr{\dfrac{2\,v\, u}{v \m u}} a
\tl{05}
\end{equation}
From \eqref{05}
\begin{equation}
\mr dx \e 2\,\dfrac{v\mr du\m u\mr d v}{\plr{v\m u}^2}\, a \,,\qquad \mr dy \e 2\,\dfrac{v^2\mr du\m u^2\mr d v}{\plr{v\m u}^2}\, a
\tl{06}
\end{equation}
From \eqref{06} the left hand side of \eqref{01} is transformed as follows
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mr dy}{\mr dx} \e \dfrac{v^2\mr du\m u^2\mr d v}{v\mr du\m u\mr d v}
\tl{07}
\end{equation}
For the transformation of the right hand side of \eqref{01} we have at first, see Figure-01,
\begin{align}
B_x & \e \plr{B_{\mr A}}_x\p \plr{B_{\mr B}}_x \e \dfrac{\mu_0 \mr I}{2\pi}\plr{\dfrac{\sin\theta_{\mr A}}{\mr{PA}} \m \dfrac{\sin\theta_{\mr B}}{\mr{PB}}}
\tl{08a}\\
B_y & \e \plr{B_{\mr A}}_y\p \plr{B_{\mr B}}_y\e \dfrac{\mu_0 \mr I}{2\pi}\plr{\dfrac{\cos\theta_{\mr B}}{\mr{PB}} \m \dfrac{\cos\theta_{\mr A}}{\mr{PA}}}
\tl{08b}
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{B_y}{B_x} \e \dfrac{\plr{\dfrac{\cos\theta_{\mr B}}{\mr{PB}} \m \dfrac{\cos\theta_{\mr A}}{\mr{PA}}}}{\plr{\dfrac{\sin\theta_{\mr A}}{\mr{PA}} \m \dfrac{\sin\theta_{\mr B}}{\mr{PB}}}}
\tl{09}
\end{equation}
From the geometry of the problem
\begin{equation}
\mr{PA} \e \dfrac{y}{\sin\theta_{\mr A}} \,,\qquad \mr{PB} \e \dfrac{y}{\sin\theta_{\mr B}}
\tl{10}
\end{equation}
and \eqref{09} yields
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dfrac{B_y}{B_x} & \e \dfrac{\plr{\sin\theta_{\mr B}\cos\theta_{\mr B} \m \sin\theta_{\mr A}\cos\theta_{\mr A}}}{\plr{\sin^2\theta_{\mr A} \m \sin^2\theta_{\mr B}}}\\
&\e \dfrac{\plr{\dfrac{\tan\theta_{\mr B}}{\cos^2\theta_{\mr A}}\m{\dfrac{\tan\theta_{\mr A}}{\cos^2\theta_{\mr B}}}}}{\plr{\dfrac{\tan^2\theta_{\mr A}}{\cos^2\theta_{\mr B}}\m{\dfrac{\tan^2\theta_{\mr B}}{\cos^2\theta_{\mr A}}}}}\\
& \e \dfrac{\tan\theta_{\mr B}\plr{1\p\tan^2\theta_{\mr A}}\m\tan\theta_{\mr A}\plr{1\p\tan^2\theta_{\mr B}}}{\tan^2\theta_{\mr A}\plr{1\p\tan^2\theta_{\mr B}}\m\tan^2\theta_{\mr B}\plr{1\p\tan^2\theta_{\mr A}}} \\
& \e \dfrac{\tan\theta_{\mr A}\tan\theta_{\mr B}\m 1}{\tan\theta_{\mr A}\p\tan\theta_{\mr B}}\e\m\dfrac{1}{\tan\plr{\theta_{\mr A}\p\theta_{\mr B}}}\e \tan\blr{\plr{\theta_{\mr A}\p\theta_{\mr B}}\m\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\\
\end{split}
\tl{11}
\end{equation}
Replacing $\:\tan\theta_{\mr A},\tan\theta_{\mr B}\:$ with $\:u,v\:$  respectively
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{B_y}{B_x} \e \dfrac{u\,v \m 1}{u \p v}
\tl{12}
\end{equation}
Combining \eqref{01}, \eqref{07} and \eqref{12} we have the differential equation in terms of the new variables $\:u,v$
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{v^2\mr du\m u^2\mr d v}{v\mr du\m u\mr d v}\e \dfrac{u\,v \m 1}{u \p v}
\tl{13}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mr du}{u\plr{1\p u^2}} \e \dfrac{\mr dv}{v\plr{1\p v^2}}
\tl{14}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mr d u^2}{ u^2}\m\dfrac{\mr d\plr{1\p u^2}}{\plr{1\p u^2}} \e \dfrac{\mr d v^2}{ v^2}\m\dfrac{\mr d\plr{1\p v^2}}{\plr{1\p v^2}} 
\tl{15}
\end{equation}
which integrated yields
\begin{equation}
\ln\plr{\dfrac{u^2}{1\p u^2}} \e \ln\plr{\dfrac{v^2}{1\p v^2}}\p \texttt{constant}
\tl{16}
\end{equation}
But
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{u^2}{1\p u^2} \e \dfrac{\tan^2\theta_{\mr A}}{1\p \tan^2\theta_{\mr A}}\e \sin^2\theta_{\mr A}\,,\quad \dfrac{v^2}{1\p v^2} \e \dfrac{\tan^2\theta_{\mr B}}{1\p \tan^2\theta_{\mr B}}\e \sin^2\theta_{\mr B} 
\tl{17}
\end{equation}
and equation \eqref{16} gives
\begin{equation}
\ln\plr{\sin^2\theta_{\mr A}} \e \ln\plr{\sin^2\theta_{\mr B}}\p \texttt{constant}^\prime
\tl{18}
\end{equation}
Because of symmetry with respect to the $\:\mr x\m$axis we consider that $\:\theta_{\mr A},\theta_{\mr B} \bl\in \plr{0,\pi}\:$ so $\:\sin\theta_{\mr A},\sin\theta_{\mr B} \gr 0\:$  and from \eqref{18}
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
\sin\theta_{\mr B} \e \lambda \sin\theta_{\mr A}\:\:\vp} 
\tl{19}
\end{equation}
where $\:\lambda\:$ a constant factor.
From equations \eqref{10} and \eqref{19} we have
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
\dfrac{\mr{PA}}{\mr{PB}}\e \lambda\,, \quad  \lambda \bl\in \mathbb R^{\p}\:\:\vp} 
\tl{20}
\end{equation}
that is

The magnetic field line corresponding to a positive factor $\:\lambda\:$ is the geometric locus of points $\:\mr P\:$ that see the edges of the straight segment $\:\mr{AB}\:$ with ratio $\:\lambda$. From geometry we know that these geometric loci are circles as shown in Figure-02.

In Figure-A details of the construction of a magnetic field line of $\lambda$-factor are shown.
Although we have proved that a magnetic field line is a perfect circle, we will give the parametric equations of this curve making use of equations \eqref{04} repeated here for convenience
\begin{align}
x_\theta\plr{\theta_{\mr A}} & \e \dfrac{\tan\theta_{\mr B}\p\tan\theta_{\mr A}}{\tan\theta_{\mr B}\m\tan\theta_{\mr A}}\, a  
\tl{21a}\\
y_\theta\plr{\theta_{\mr A}} & \e \dfrac{2\tan\theta_{\mr B} \tan\theta_{\mr A}}{\tan\theta_{\mr B} \m \tan\theta_{\mr A}}\, a
\tl{21b}
\end{align}
In above equation we replace the angle $\:\theta_{\mr B}\:$ as function of the angle $\:\theta_{\mr A}\:$ according to \eqref{19}
\begin{equation}
\theta_{\mr B} \e \arcsin\plr{\lambda\sin\theta_{\mr A}}
\tl{22}
\end{equation}
so the $\:{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr A}}}}\m$parametric equations for the  magnetic field line of $\:{\color{blue}{\bl\lambda}}\m$factor are
\begin{align}
x_{\color{blue}{\bl\lambda}}\plr{{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr A}}}}} & \e \dfrac{\tan\blr{\arcsin\plr{{\color{blue}{\bl\lambda}}\sin{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr A}}}}}\vp}\p\tan{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr A}}}}}{\tan\blr{\arcsin\plr{{\color{blue}{\bl\lambda}}\sin{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr A}}}}}\vp}\m\tan{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr A}}}}}\, a  
\tl{23a}\\
y_{\color{blue}{\bl\lambda}}\plr{{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr A}}}}} & \e \dfrac{2\tan\blr{\arcsin\plr{{\color{blue}{\bl\lambda}}\sin{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr A}}}}}\vp}\tan{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr A}}}}}{\tan\blr{\arcsin\plr{{\color{blue}{\bl\lambda}}\sin{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr A}}}}}\vp}\m\tan{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr A}}}}}\, a
\tl{23b}\\
\vp{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr A}}}} & \bl\in \plr{0,\pi}\,, \qquad  {\color{blue}{\bl\lambda}}\bl\in \plr{0,\p\infty}
\tl{23c}
\end{align}
Using above parametric equations the magnetic field lines for various values of $\:{\color{blue}{\bl\lambda}}\:$ are shown in Figure-03. This Figure is precisely identical to Figure-02.





Great work! I wondered if the field lines in this case were shaped like perfect circles and you proved it!

@Euclid Looked On Beauty Bare : I was suprised when in the end I did reach equation \eqref{20}. I am convinced that my solution is correct. I expect you know something about the two harmonic conjugates points of the segment $:\mathrm{AB}:$  and so why \eqref{20} represents a circle of diameter the straight segment that joins them.

Each circle is a circle of Apollonius. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Circle_of_Apollonius
I got a BSc in physics over 35 years ago and never worked in the field. I struggled to earn the degree since my math skills were never that strong and they have waned considerably with time. I have long standing interest in the geometrical principles that relate physical theories to nature hence the nature of my question.

$\require{\cancel}
\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} 
\newcommand{\e}{\bl=}
\newcommand{\p}{\bl+}
\newcommand{\m}{\bl-}
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbf {#1}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal {#1}}
\newcommand{\mr}[1]{\mathrm {#1}}
\newcommand{\mf}[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\bl>}
\newcommand{\les}{\bl<}
\newcommand{\greq}{\bl\ge}
\newcommand{\leseq}{\bl\le}
\newcommand{\il}[1]{$\:#1\:$}
\newcommand{\plr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\blr}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\clr}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\vlr}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\Vlr}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\lara}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lav}[1]{\left\langle#1\right|}
\newcommand{\vra}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavra}[2]{\left\langle#1|#2\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavvra}[3]{\left\langle#1\right|#2\left|#3\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\vp}{\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\newcommand{\Vp}[1]{\vphantom{#1}}
\newcommand{\hp}[1]{\hphantom{#1}} 
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}$
ANSWER$\bl{\m02}$
The magnetic field lines from steady electric currents flowing in two parallel wires of infinite length.
In Figures Figure-04 and Figure-05 we have a system of two parallel wires $\:\texttt{A,B}\:$ with steady electric currents $\:\mr I_\texttt{A}\e \xi\,\mr I\:$ and $\:\mr  I_\texttt{B}\e \eta\,\mr I \:$ respectively. The coefficients $\:\xi,\eta\:$ are real numbers. If $\:\xi\cdot\eta \gr 0\:$ the two currents are flowing in the same direction while if $\:\xi\cdot\eta \les 0\:$ the two currents are flowing in opposite directions.
Now we assert and we'll prove that :

If $\:\texttt P\:$ is a point on a magnetic field line and $\:p \e \mr{PA},\:q \e \mr{PB}\:$ are the variable lengths shown in Figures Figure-04 and Figure-05 then along this magnetic field line the following surprisingly enough simple equation is valid
\begin{equation}
p^\xi\, q^\eta \e \texttt{constant}
\tl{A-01}
\end{equation}

From Figure-05 we have
\begin{align}
p^2 & \e \mr{PA}^2 \e \plr{x \p a}^2 \p y^2
\tl{A-02a}\\
q^2 & \e \mr{PB}^2 \e \plr{x \m a}^2 \p y^2
\tl{A-02b}
\end{align}
so by \eqref{A-01} a magnetic field line satisfies implicitly the following equation
\begin{equation}
\blr{\plr{x \p a}^2 \p y^2\vp}^\xi\, \blr{\plr{x \m a}^2 \p y^2\vp}^\eta \e \texttt{constant}
\tl{A-03}
\end{equation}
We'll use above equation to sketch the family of magnetic field lines for some special simple cases where the coefficients $\:\xi,\eta\:$ are integers.









$\bl{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$
APPENDIX : Proof of equation \eqref{A-01}

The magnetic field lines are plane curves obeying the differential equation
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mr dy}{\mr dx} \e \dfrac{B_y\plr{x,y}}{B_x\plr{x,y}}
\tl{D-01}
\end{equation}
This equation was solved by a proper change of variables. The new variables are
\begin{equation}
p \e \mr{PA} \,,\qquad q \e \mr{PB} 
\tl{D-02}
\end{equation}
where $\:\plr{\mr{PA},\mr{PB}}\:$ the lengths of the straight segments shown in  Figure-04 and Figure-05.


Using the geometry of the problem the differential equation \eqref{D-01} with respect to $\:\plr{x,y}\:$ is transformed to a differential equation  with respect to $\:\plr{p,q}$. Its solution is summarized  to the surprisingly enough simple equation
\begin{equation}
p^\xi\, q^\eta \e \texttt{constant}
\nonumber
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\mr{PA}^\xi\cdot \mr{PB}^\eta\e\lambda\,,\quad \lambda \bl\in \mathbb R^{\p}
\tl{D-03}
\end{equation}
At first from the geometry of the problem we have
\begin{align}
\plr{x \p a}^2 \p y^2 & \e \mr{PA}^2 \e p^2
\tl{D-03a}\\
\plr{x \m a}^2 \p y^2 & \e \mr{PB}^2 \e q^2
\tl{D-03b}
\end{align}
Subtracting above equations side by side we have
\begin{equation}
\plr{x \p a}^2 \m \plr{x \m a}^2 \e p^2 \m q^2 \quad \bl\implies
\boxed{\:\:x \e \dfrac{p^2 \m q^2}{4a}\:\:}
\tl{D-04}
\end{equation}
while adding them
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \plr{x \p a}^2 \p \plr{x \m a}^2 \p 2 y^2 \e p^2 \p q^2\: \bl\implies\:  2x^2 \p 2a^2 \p 2 y^2 \e p^2 \p q^2\: \bl\implies\\
& y^2 \e \dfrac{p^2 \p q^2 }{2}\m x^2 \m a^2\:\stackrel{\eqref{D-04}}{\bl\implies}\:y^2 \e \dfrac{p^2 \p q^2 }{2}\m \plr{\dfrac{p^2 \m q^2}{4a}}^2 \m a^2 \: \bl\implies\\
& y^2 \e \dfrac{p^2 \p q^2 }{2}\m \plr{\dfrac{p^2 \m q^2}{4a}}^2 \m a^2 \\
\end{split}
\nonumber
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
 y^2 \e \dfrac{8a^2\plr{p^2 \p q^2 }\m\plr{p^4 \p q^4\m 2p^2 q^2}\m 16a^4\vp}{ 16a^2\vp}\:\:}
\tl{D-05}
\end{equation}
From \eqref{D-04}
\begin{equation}
\mr dx \e \dfrac{p\,{\color{blue}{\mr dp}}\m q\,{\color{blue}{\mr dq}}}{2a}
\tl{D-06}
\end{equation}
From \eqref{D-05}
\begin{equation}
32a^2 y\mr dy \e \plr{16a^2 p \m 4p^3\p 4q^2 p}{\color{blue}{\mr dp}} \p\plr{16a^2 q \m 4q^3\p 4p^2 q}{\color{blue}{\mr dq}}
\nonumber
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\mr dy \e \dfrac{\plr{4a^2 p \m p^3\p q^2 p}{\color{blue}{\mr dp}} \p\plr{4a^2 q \m q^3\p p^2 q}{\color{blue}{\mr dq}}}{8a^2 y} 
\tl{D-07}
\end{equation}
From \eqref{D-06},\eqref{D-07}
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:\dfrac{\mr dy}{\mr dx} \e \dfrac{\plr{4a^2 p \m p^3\p q^2 p\vp}{\color{blue}{\mr dp}} \p\plr{4a^2 q \m q^3\p p^2 q\vp}{\color{blue}{\mr dq}}}{4a\plr{p\,{\color{blue}{\mr dp}}\m q\,{\color{blue}{\mr dq}}\vp}y}\:\:}
\tl{D-08}
\end{equation}
For the transformation of the right hand side of \eqref{D-01} we have at first, see Figure-05,
\begin{align}
B_x & \e \plr{B_{\mr A}}_x\p \plr{B_{\mr B}}_x \e \dfrac{\mu_0\,\mr I}{2\pi}\plr{\m\dfrac{\xi\sin\theta_{\mr A}}{\mr{PA}} \m \dfrac{\eta\sin\theta_{\mr B}}{\mr{PB}}}
\tl{D-09a}\\
B_y & \e \plr{B_{\mr A}}_y\p \plr{B_{\mr B}}_y\e \dfrac{\mu_0\, \mr I}{2\pi}\plr{\hp\m\dfrac{\xi\cos\theta_{\mr A}}{\mr{PA}}\p\dfrac{\eta\cos\theta_{\mr B}}{\mr{PB}} }
\tl{D-09b}
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{B_y}{B_x} \e \m\dfrac{\plr{\dfrac{\xi\cos\theta_{\mr A}}{\mr{PA}}\p\dfrac{\eta\cos\theta_{\mr B}}{\mr{PB}} }}{\plr{\dfrac{\xi\sin\theta_{\mr A}}{\mr{PA}}\p\dfrac{\eta\sin\theta_{\mr B}}{\mr{PB}} }} 
\e \m\dfrac{\plr{\xi\,q\cos\theta_{\mr A}\p \eta\,p\cos\theta_{\mr B}\vp}}{\plr{\xi\,q\sin\theta_{\mr A}\p \eta\,p\sin\theta_{\mr B}\vp}}
\tl{D-10}
\end{equation}
Since for the trigonometric functions we have
\begin{align}
\cos\theta_{\mr A} \e \dfrac{x\p a}{\mr{PA}} \e \dfrac{\dfrac{p^2 \m q^2}{4a}\p a}{p}\quad &\bl\implies \cos\theta_{\mr A}\e\dfrac{p^2 \m q^2\p 4a^2}{4ap}
\tl{D-11a}\\
\cos\theta_{\mr B} \e \dfrac{x\m a}{\mr{PB}} \e \dfrac{\dfrac{p^2 \m q^2}{4a}\m a}{q}\quad &\bl\implies\cos\theta_{\mr B}\e\dfrac{p^2 \m q^2\m 4a^2}{4aq}
\tl{D-11b}\\
\sin\theta_{\mr A} \e \dfrac{y}{\mr{PA}}\quad &\bl\implies \sin\theta_{\mr A}\e\dfrac{y}{p}
\tl{D-11c}\\
\sin\theta_{\mr B} \e \dfrac{y}{\mr{PB}}\quad &\bl\implies  \sin\theta_{\mr B}\e\dfrac{y}{q}
\tl{D-11d}
\end{align}
equation \eqref{D-10} yields
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
 \dfrac{B_y}{B_x}\e \dfrac{\plr{\xi\,q^4\m\eta\,p^4\m\xi q^2p^2\p\eta p^2q^2\m 4\xi a^2q^2\p 4\eta a^2 p^2\vp}}{4a\plr{\xi\, q^2\p \eta\, p^2\vp}y}\:\:}
\tl{D-12}
\end{equation}
Using expressions \eqref{D-08},\eqref{D-12} the differential equation \eqref{D-01} is transformed as follows
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\plr{4a^2 p \m p^3\p q^2 p\vp}{\color{blue}{\mr dp}} \p\plr{4a^2 q \m q^3\p p^2 q\vp}{\color{blue}{\mr dq}}}{\cancel{4a}\plr{p\,{\color{blue}{\mr dp}}\m q\,{\color{blue}{\mr dq}}\vp}\cancel{y}}   \e \dfrac{\plr{\xi\,q^4\m\eta\,p^4\m\xi q^2p^2\p\eta p^2q^2\m 4\xi a^2q^2\p 4\eta a^2 p^2\vp}}{\cancel{4a}\plr{\xi\, q^2\p \eta\, p^2\vp}\cancel{y}}
\nonumber
\end{equation}
that is 
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\plr{4a^2 p \m p^3\p q^2 p\vp}{\color{blue}{\mr dp}} \p\plr{4a^2 q \m q^3\p p^2 q\vp}{\color{blue}{\mr dq}}}{\plr{p{\color{blue}{\mr dp}}\m q{\color{blue}{\mr dq}}\vp}}   \e \dfrac{\plr{\xi\,q^4\m\eta\,p^4\m\xi q^2p^2\p\eta p^2q^2\m 4\xi a^2q^2\p 4\eta a^2 p^2\vp}}{\plr{\xi\, q^2\p \eta\, p^2\vp}}
\nonumber
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\overbrace{\blr{p\plr{\xi\,q^4\m\eta\,p^4\m\xi q^2p^2\p\eta p^2q^2\m 4\xi a^2q^2\p 4\eta a^2 p^2\vp}  \m  \plr{\xi\, q^2\p \eta\, p^2\vp} \plr{4a^2 p \m p^3\p q^2 p\vp}}}^{\m 8\xi a^2pq^2}{\color{blue}{\mr dp}}\e \\
&\underbrace{\blr{q\plr{\xi\,q^4\m\eta\,p^4\m\xi q^2p^2\p\eta p^2q^2\m 4\xi a^2q^2\p 4\eta a^2 p^2\vp}  \p \plr{\xi\, q^2\p \eta\, p^2\vp} \plr{4a^2 q \m q^3\p p^2 q\vp}}}_{\p 8\eta a^2qp^2}{\color{blue}{\mr dq}}\\
\end{split}
\nonumber
\end{equation}
so 
\begin{equation}
\xi\dfrac{{\color{blue}{\mr dp}}}{p} \p \eta\dfrac{{\color{blue}{\mr dq}}}{q}\e 0
\tl{D-13}
\end{equation}
By integration of above equation we have proved equation \eqref{A-01} repeated here for convenience
\begin{equation}
p^\xi\, q^\eta \e \texttt{constant}
\tl{D-14}
\end{equation}


Great! When ξ⋅η>0 it seems the field lines are orthogonal at the point where they appear to cross.  I say appear to cross because it must be the case that the direction of circulation makes an abrupt 90 degree turn. I suppose the B field is approximately hyperbolic near this point.

@Euclid Looked On Beauty Bare : A magnetic field line could not intersect itself unless the field vector is the zero vector on the intersection point. That's why such a point is called neutral point. On the other hand, indeed ,since the drawings are precise it seems that such a curve intersects itself orthogonally. I'll check it.

@Euclid Looked On Beauty Bare  You could see electric field line  that intersects itself and neutral point in my answer here : Field lines of two charges whose algebraic sum is not zero. It seems that orthogonality is valid also there.

Indeed at the neutral point the two B fields vectors associated with A and B are equal and opposite so the magnitude of the field is zero there. If the magnitude is zero is it illogical to ascribe some sort of directional quality to this zero point?

I also looked your excellent work on the electric field lines. It is very intriguing to see the neutral point and how the shape of the field lines tend to converge on a circle and straight line when the charges are unequal.

Frobenius great work again! Nice to see in Figure 09 the neutral point and the shape the field line in which it resides when the magnitudes of opposing currents is an unequal.
